# identify successive chars and nums

Tags: c#, regex

*(very new to regex)* 
I have an input string which is a combination of digits (0-9), alphabets (A-Z, a-z) and special characters. How can i identify the follwoing examples using regex? Examples: 123a, abc2, 12ab, ab12, 1@3a, @a13, %1a3, a$13.

Valid examples:
`123 + 456` Or, using any other operator/braces like

```
*, - , /, ), (
```

`abc * efg` Or, using any other operator/braces like

```
*, - , /, ), (
```

Invalid examples:

```
(123a + abc2 * 12ab / ab12 ) + (1@3a + @a13 - %1a3 * a$13)

123a + abc2 

abc2 * 12ab
```

Or, using any other operator/braces like  `*, +, - , /, ), (`

Comment: These seem like rather arbitrary examples.  Are you trying to detect a pattern?  Are you looking for anything that has more than one group of digits/alphabets/special characters and a length of 4 characters?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Please also provide some *negative* examples. Which strings should your regex *not* match?

Comment: `Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^(123a|abc2|12ab|ab12|1@3a|@a13|%1a3|a\$13)$")` ;-)

Comment: You should read [this](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm). Untill and unless you try and come up with your own regex, I am sure you cannot handle all the cases. Down the line, you will, for sure think, what does this part of my regex do? This is pretty simple only i guess. Read the [basics](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I think for small examples it is possible generate a regular expression but will be very big and hard to understand. For this problem you can use sorting. Sort the string and compares with the original, if it is equal, the string has successive characters (BUT to find a small part of an entire string you need something more intelligent).